# Flask "send_from_directory" works in local, but doesn't in remote

Tags: python, flask, web-applications

On my flask app, I upload a file, save it to a directory and then send it back as attachment.

When I run my code on "debug" mode on my local machine using VSCode, it works as expected. But when I upload the app to the remote server, I always get a "404" error.

Any idea of what I am missing?

```
#import Flask 
from flask import Flask, request, send_from_directory
import json
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

UPLOAD_FOLDER_MR_PROPER = './tmp/mrProper/'
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER_MR_PROPER

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'index'

@app.route('/mrProper', methods=['POST'])
def handler_mrProper():
    import shortuuid

    uploaded_file = request.files['file']

    tmp_name = shortuuid.uuid()
    _, tmp_ext = uploaded_file.filename.rsplit(".", 1)
    tmp_filename = tmp_name + "." + tmp_ext

    if uploaded_file.filename != '':
        uploaded_file.save(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] + tmp_filename)

    sp = os.path.join(app.instance_path, app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] )

    # SOME IRRELEVANT PROCESSING

    return send_from_directory( app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],  
                            tmp_filename,
                            mimetype = request.files["file"].content_type,
                            as_attachment = True,
                            attachment_filename = uploaded_file.filename,
                            cache_timeout=0)

if __name__ == '__main__': 
   app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess solved the problem.

Two issues here:

1. Route: Must be absolute path: UPLOAD_FOLDER_MR_PROPER = '/var/...../tmp/mrProper/'
2. .htaccess rewrite: Adding "/app/tmp/mrProper/" solved it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).